# Getting `This is "undefined"` in JS class's method using React Scroll Spy Nav (but the question is not in React ScrollSpy Nav)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-hooks, react-scroll

I've been trying to resolve that error since yesterday, but still no luck. I'll explain briefly.

**Expectations**

I'm using React ScrollSpy Nav Library to implement active link highlighting feature on the webpage according to the currently scrolled article's id.

Don't get confused by the way I set the links, I'm just using reacti18next to adapt links for different languages, thus it's easier to dynamically add them and limit copy paste.

I want the *active link to be highlighted*, and *onClick -+- to scroll to the desired article by its id*.

When the onScroll event gets called, I get an error **"Cannot read property classList of null"** when the script attempts to add or remove .is-active className. I've been trying to solve it and came with a conclusion that what happens is (*in ascending order, reversed*):

3)

```
this.scrollTargetIds.forEach(function (r, n) {
              document.getElementById(r) ? (e = document.getElementById(r).offsetTop - (t.headerBackground ? document.querySelector("div[data-nav='list']").scrollHeight : 0), window.pageYOffset - t.offset >= e && window.pageYOffset < e + document.getElementById(r).scrollHeight ? (t.getNavLinkElement(r).classList.add(t.activeNavClass), t.clearOtherNavLinkActiveStyle(r)) : t.getNavLinkElement(r).classList.remove(t.activeNavClass), window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset >= document.body.scrollHeight && n === t.scrollTargetIds.length - 1 && (t.getNavLinkElement(r).classList.add(t.activeNavClass), t.clearOtherNavLinkActiveStyle(r))) : console.warn("".concat("react-scrollspy-nav", ": no element with id ").concat(r, " present in the DOM"));
            });
```

*t.getNavLinkElement(r)* returns null, because (here is the implementation of that function - getNavLinkElement):

2)

```
getNavLinkElement(sectionID) {
    return document.querySelector(`a[href='${this.hashIdentifier}${sectionID}']`);
  }
```

Because here this is undefined, as I explored in the devtools debugger scope's block. This is undefined there, yet r and n are = "definitions" and 0 (as expected)

3)

And here's where the this.hashIdentifier gets set:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.props = props;
    this.scrollTargetIds = this.props.scrollTargetIds;
    this.activeNavClass = this.props.activeNavClass;
    this.scrollDuration = Number(this.props.scrollDuration) || 1000;
    this.headerBackground = this.props.headerBackground === "true" ? true : false;
    this.offset = this.props.offset || 0;

    this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);

    if(this.props.router && this.props.router === "HashRouter") {
      this.homeDefaultLink = "#/";
      this.hashIdentifier = "#/#";
    } else {
      this.homeDefaultLink = "/";
      this.hashIdentifier = "#";
    }
  }
```

Classe's constructor

---

Here's my React code where I initialize the React Scrollspy Nav component, and set the links, and so on. It's Navigation component:

```
export const LeftSideNavigation = () => {
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = React.useState(false);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (!document) {
        return;
      }
      if (!document.querySelector) {
        return;
      }
      if (document.querySelector("#articles-wrapper")) {
         
        console.log(isLoaded)
        if (!(document.querySelector("#articles-wrapper") as Element).innerHTML) {
          
          return;
        }
        
        console.log((document.querySelector("#articles-wrapper") as Element).innerHTML)
        setIsLoaded(true);
       
      }
      else{
        console.log("cannot find ekement with id articles wrapper")
      } 
    }, []);
    React.useEffect(() =>{
      console.log("is loaded is", isLoaded);
    }, [isLoaded])
    const [Arr, setArr] = React.useState(window.location.toString().includes("termsOfService") ? SubLinks1 : SubLinks2);
    return (
        <Container>
          {isLoaded && 
            (<ScrollspyNav
                        scrollTargetIds={[...Arr.map((link : LinkItem) => {return(camelize(t(link.name)))})]}
                        offset={100}
                        activeNavClass="is-active"
                        scrollDuration="1000"
                        headerBackground="true"
                    ><ul>
                      _{
                        Arr === SubLinks1 ? (<ExpandableLink higherLevelLink="termsOfService" name="conditionsPages.termsOfServiceLinkText" subLinks={SubLinks1} />) : (<ExpandableLink higherLevelLink="privacyPolicy" name="conditionsPages.privacyPolicyLinkText" subLinks={SubLinks2} />)
                      }
                    
                    
                </ul>
            </ScrollspyNav>)
}
        </Container>
    )
}
```

It's articles component:

```
<ArticlesContainer id="articles-wrapper">
            <Wrapper id="definitions"><Title variant="h4">{t("privacyArticles.1.title")}</Title><Content><Trans i18nKey="privacyArticles.1.content"/></Content></Wrapper>
```

I want to understand why is "this" undefined.

**Important note!**

The code blocks I attached (besides the React component's one) are from react-scrollspy-nav node_module's folder, so I can't edit the code in those functions. I can only edit the React component's code.

PS: I installed the package via npm (to be more precise - yarn), and here's the github full source code for that lib: https://github.com/StephenWeiXu/react-scrollspy-nav. Please view it if I haven't provided enough code pieces. The lib used to work a few days ago, but I deleted the project's files by a coincidence, couldn't restore and now reimplementing everything.